# Missing dock icons

Tags: macos, dock, icon

I've got an issue with my new MacBook Pro 15″ (bought it two weeks ago).

Some icons are missing from the Dock:

[image]

The first one is Terminal, and the second one is Todoist

If I close and reopen the application it fixes the issue, but it reappears quite often.

Do you know what could be wrong with my Mac?

Here are the specs:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?  Control click and keep in dock. Or drag to new location on the dock when the app is running.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try it when the bug will happen again. Just temporarily fixed it with the command "killall dock"

Comment: @bjbk You are right, when I move the app the icon is back. Do you have any fix for that? (even if your answer is a temporary fix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current best answer to my problem thanks to bjbk's comment:

Moving an app to a new location within the dock fixes the issue temporarily.

Comment: The issue is the opened app permanently belongs to the dock if you move it.